# Gettext and PHP 5.3.5 xampp - Use of undefined constant LC_MESSAGES - assumed 'LC_MESSAGES' in

Tags: php, gettext, setlocale

I am getting the following error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant LC_MESSAGES - assumed 'LC_MESSAGES' in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xampp\phptest\resources\testi18n.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xampp\phptest\resources\testi18n.php on line 19

Deprecated: setlocale() [function.setlocale]: Passing locale category name as string is deprecated. Use the LC_* -constants instead in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xampp\phptest\resources\testi18n.php on line 19
```

the code:

```
<?php

  setlocale( LC_MESSAGES, $_GET['language']);

  bindtextdomain('messages', 'locale');
...
 ?>
```

I did test gettext extension is installed with php (it supported)

Answer (score 3):

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) (emphasis mine):

> LC_MESSAGES for system responses (**available if PHP was compiled with libintl**)

`LC_ALL` may be a useful replacement for your purposes.

Comment: thanks Pekka, but how I can compile with libintl where I get it and steps to install and congif it.

Answer (score 1):

please DON'T use `LC_ALL`, because you may have very bad side effect using languages like French.

In my case `floatval()` and float conversion to string use the coma instead of the dot as the decimal separator. And it just put a bug mess in my db.

Comment: Well, you will have to use `LC_MONETARY` and `LC_TIME` etc. then as well to set the right locale.

Comment: been there, an awesome hidden bug 